# git serverside hook - pre-receive or update for checking code formatting for Java - How to use it?

Tags: git, githooks

I am trying to add a server-side check which will be triggered from git push - to check if the committed code / difference is properly formatted or not.
Code formatter (Eclipse Code Formatter) exists on client side and this is a final check.
So far, I came across pre-receive hook and update hook with very few examples.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Git update hook servers side, also doing and checking formatting of code
# check each branch being pushed
# Exit status 0 = all OK
# Exit status 1 = Problem, commit will be rejected

echo "update hook initiated"
# get different values (They are default - from update hook)
ref_name=$1
old_rev=$2
new_rev=$3

# only check branches, not tags or bare commits
#if [ -z $(echo $ref_name | grep "refs/heads/") ]; then
#  exit 0
#fi

# don't check empty branches
if [ "$(expr "${new_rev}" : '0*$')" -ne 0 ]; then
  exit 0
fi
```

Only executing this fails:

```
remote: : Permission denied
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
```

Any pointers would be great!

Comment: Does the hook resides at the servers side in `.git/hooks/update`? Is the script executable?

Comment: Yes it resides at the location you have mentioned. Yes it's executable.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
remote: : Permission denied
```

is quite suggestive.  Note the colon-space-colon pattern here.  Your Git added the `remote:` , including the first colon-and-space, so the message that came *from* the remote—from the server trying to run the update hook—was actually:

```
: Permission denied
```

That is, the hook appears to be running a command that has no characters.  Normally you would get `command not found` here; it's not clear why you're getting `Permission denied`.  In any case this doesn't seem possible given the hook you showed.  Perhaps the server is running something different.  If it is running a bash script, though, try adding the `-x` option:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash -x
```

which will let you see each line as it executes, and help find the line with the empty command.  Here's an example of running such a script:

```
$ cat > /tmp/foo.bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash -x
""
$ chmod +x /tmp/foo.bash
$ /tmp/foo.bash
+ ''
/tmp/foo.bash: line 2: : command not found
$
```

The `+ ''` line shows the attempt to execute the empty command on line 2, and is followed by the detailed error message.